# what's the difference between using one output node and two nodes to classify two class with ANN

Tags: neural-network

When Using ANN to classify two classes task. The output nodes can be either one or two. For example.
`The architecture of NN is 400*10*1 for one Node,  and 400*10*2 for two Node.`
 If I Use two nodes. It will give two delta from the output layer when in the process of back-propagation. But with one node, it just propagate one delta back.

**Are the any difference between that?**

Answer (score 1):

Difference being that second NN is doing bunch of redundant work. Given that all the data either falls in one class or another, there is no need to have two nodes at output layer. Adding two nodes will only make the system calculate two complementary deltas. This does not give any new information to the system or does not allow it perform any better.

Comment: does the  second NN hurt the neural network.  I'm not mean hurt the training time. I'm mean the precise of the neural network

Comment: The second output node should not hurt the precision of the prediction. But be sure to put constraint such that both of them do not come up with same output (i.e. 0-0 or 1-1)

Comment: If you use two output signals, you would gain the possibility of guessing which of the two classes an edge case belongs to - by comparing the magnitude of the two values.